# Kentico custom email provider - prevent email from being sent

Tags: asp.net, .net, email, kentico

working on custom email provider where in certain situation I prevent email from being sent out.

note:  all email currently being sent out via Kentico email queue and needs to stay that way.

All options I tried to delete/archive/stop sending email all result in the email staying in Kentioc email queue with status  sending or waiting.

This is the code I am trying, see option in "***if (stopEmail){..}***"

```
 protected override void SendEmailAsyncInternal(string siteName, MailMessage message, SMTPServerInfo smtpServer, EmailToken emailToken)
{

    string contentAll = "";
    bool stopEmail = false;

    // read email content
    try
    {
        if (message.AlternateViews.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < message.AlternateViews.Count; i++)
            {

                var stream = message.AlternateViews[i].ContentStream;
                if (stream.CanRead)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, false, 1000, true)) 
                    {
                        contentAll += reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

            }


        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLogProvider.LogInformation("CMSCustom baned emails", "EMAIL SENDOUT", ex.Message + ", <br /> email content:<br /> " + contentAll);
    }


    // check if BANNED dmoains are in email
    string bannedEmails = "@somedomain.com";

    if (contentAll.Contains(bannedEmails))
    {
        stopEmail = true;

    }

    // if banned email found, stop email from being sent
    if (stopEmail)
    {
        //
        var m = new EmailMessage(message);
        var mi = EmailInfoProvider.SetEmailInfo(m, SiteContext.CurrentSiteID);
        //opt 4  - Stuck in email queue - sending/waiting
        //SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer.ServerName);
        //client.SendAsyncCancel();


        // opt 3 - Stuck in email queue - sending/waiting
        //EmailHelper.Queue.CancelSending();

        // opt 2 - Stuck in email queue - sending/waiting
       // EmailHelper.Queue.Delete(mi.EmailID);


        //opt 1 - Stuck in email queue - sending/waiting
        //mi.EmailStatus = EmailStatusEnum.Archived;
        //mi.Update();

        return;
    }



    base.SendEmailAsyncInternal(siteName, message, smtpServer, emailToken);




}
```

Any idea how I can successfully remove/delete get rid on the specific email?

Thanks ):

Answer (score 0):

Try the following line:

```
EmailInfoProvider.DeleteEmailInfo(mi.EmailID);
```

Using `EmailHelper.Queue.CancelSending()` has a wider impact and effects the current mail send, rather than just the current email.

Looking at the code from the Kentico admin pages, `EmailHelper.Queue.Delete(mi.EmailID);` should work, and ultimately calls the same method.  Do you see any errors in the event log that let you know why the email has been deleted?

Comment: No error in event log.  EMails are still stuck in email queue with status of "sending".  can not seem to be able to delete them.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In order to move emails to "Sent Emails" you need to call `EmailProvider.OnSendCompleted(AsyncCompletedEventArgs)`

I use the following function to mark emails as complete in Kentico 9. The emails still show up under the "Sent Emails" tab, but the emails are never actually sent.

```
private void CancelSend(EmailToken eToken)
{
    var completedEvent = new AsyncCompletedEventArgs(null, false, eToken);
    base.OnSendCompleted(completedEvent);
}
```

Combined with your code we get:

```
// if banned email found, stop email from being sent
if (stopEmail)
{
    CancelSend(emailToken);
    return;
}
```